# SQL: select query

Tags: sql, oracle

I have these tables:

- Member (IdMember, name, nbFollower)
- Follower (IdMember, IdFollower, date)
- Friend (IdMember, IdFriend)
- Photo (IdPhoto, datePhoto, IdMember)
- Comment (IdPhoto, IdMember, no, content)
- Like (IdPhoto, IdMember)

**no** is the order of comment written by a member on a photo

I want to select the name of the members who left more than 3 comments on the same photo.

I did this but it doesn't work:

```
SELECT name 
FROM MEMBER M, COMMENT C, PHOTO P
WHERE M.IdMember = C.IdMember = P.IdMember
  AND M.IdMember IN (SELECT IdMember 
                     FROM COMMENT
                     GROUP BY IdMember
                     HAVING COUNT(no) >= 3)
```

How can I change my query?

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is close, but you need to aggregate in the `Comment` table by *both* the member *and* the photo.  Try this:

```
SELECT name FROM MEMBER M, COMMENT C, PHOTO P
WHERE M.IdMember = C.IdMember = P.IdMember
AND M.IdMember IN
(
    SELECT IdMember
    FROM Comment
    GROUP BY IdMember, IdPhoto
    HAVING COUNT(*) >= 3
)
```

But really I would rather write this query using explicit joins everywhere:

```
SELECT name
FROM MEMBER m
INNER JOIN COMMENT c1
    ON m.IdMember = c1.IdMember
INNER JOIN PHOTO p
    ON c1.IdMember = p.IdMember
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT IdMember
    FROM Comment
    GROUP BY IdMember, IdPhoto
    HAVING COUNT(*) >= 3
) c2
    ON c1.IdMember = c2.IdMember
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case you don't need to join the `Photo` table because the only column you use from that table is `IdPhoto` and you already have that information in `Comment` table.

You can also directly join the subquery to the `Member` table without bringing the `Comment` table one more time.

As already said, you also have to add the IdPhoto in your group by clause, to count the number of post from the **same Member** on the **same Photo**

Have a try with this :

```
SELECT DISTINCT M.name
    FROM MEMBER M, (SELECT IdMember 
                 FROM COMMENT
                 GROUP BY IdMember, IdPhoto
                 HAVING COUNT(no) >= 3) C
    WHERE M.IdMember = C.IdMember;
```

Or with ANSI syntax :

```
SELECT DISTINCT M.name
    FROM MEMBER M
      INNER JOIN (SELECT IdMember 
                 FROM COMMENT
                 GROUP BY IdMember, IdPhoto
                 HAVING COUNT(no) >= 3) C
    ON M.IdMember = C.IdMember;
```